# How to use strings from a resource file, in the model (MVC Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application, that has multiple languages. In my views, I use my resource files to reference a single string, that gets translated to whatever language the user has selected. Example:

```
@using ResLend = MyWebApp.Resources.Lend

...

@Html.Label(ResLend.LabelName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Where `LabelName` is a defined string in resource files, in multiple languages:

```
Resources\Lend.resx
Resources\Lend.da.resx
Resources\Lend.nl.resx
```

I now want to make a custom error message in a creation form, where the error message gets translated according to the selected language. Right now, this is my model:

```
[Key]
public int OrderID { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field \"Name\" must be filled!")]
public String Name { get; set; }
```

How can I use my resource files here, to translate the error message? Do I violate any principles of MVC by doing it like this? Do I have other options to make these custom translated error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my resources in the controller like this, which works just fine:

```
using Res = MyProject.Resources.Resources;

...

ViewBag.MyMessage = Res.MyMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatic use the resource from the current language ( example: `Global.Error_FieldName`  )

Add `ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global),` to the Attribute.

Change the `ErrorMessage="The field \"Name\" must be filled!"` by `ErrorMessageResourceName="Error_FieldName"`

> When trying to change the translated error you'll have to overwrite the validation.

Comment: I forgot about this question, but I have found a simpler solution that covers my needs. Thanks for the answer though.